# Swift JSONSerialization implicitly convert double value to string

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I want convert a json string which contains a double field to JSON object using JSONSerialization.data function.   I print the result json object and it shows the double field as string.   The following is the sample code:

```
let test = "{\"statusCode\":2.334}"

do {
    let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: test.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)!, options: [])
    print(responseJSON)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

The responseJSON as following:

```
{
    statusCode = "2.334";
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it, in general, all JSON serialization engine will convert double
   value to string or it is only happen in Swift JSON serialization?
2. Anyway to force JSONSerialization to output double, not string?

Comment: That is probably just an artifact of how NSDictionary is printed. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 and use Swift types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is purely an artifact of how the value is printed out — the value you get is in fact a `Double`. You can confirm this yourself with the following:

```
import Foundation

let test = "{\"statusCode\":2.334}"

do {
    let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: test.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
    print(responseJSON["statusCode"] is Double) // => true
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```