# Swift: Incorrect Base64 Encoding

Tags: python, swift

I am attempting to convert a block of code from python and it involved encoding a json string to base64. My attempt on Swift does not produce the same base64 encoded string.

Python:

```
payload_nonce = datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()
payload = {"request": "/v1/mytrades", "nonce": payload_nonce}
encoded_payload = json.dumps(payload).encode()
b64 = base64.b64encode(encoded_payload)
print(b64) 
//prints b'eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjogIi92MS9teXRyYWRlcyIsICJub25jZSI6IDE2NjUzMzEyMDAuMH0='
```

Swift:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let date = formatter.date(from: "10/10/2022")

let payloadNonce = date!.timeIntervalSince1970
payload = [
    "request": "/v1/mytrades",
    "nonce": String(describing: payloadNonce)
]
            
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payload)
    let b64 = json.base64EncodedString()
    print(b64)
    //prints eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjoiXC92MVwvbXl0cmFkZXMiLCJub25jZSI6IjE2NjUzMzEyMDAuMCJ9
} catch {//handle error}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you compared the two json strings the products produce before base64 encoding!? *They* are the thing with different behavior here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding the Python payload:

```
{"request": "/v1/mytrades", "nonce": 1665331200.0}
```

Decoding the Swift payload:

```
{"request":"\/v1\/mytrades","nonce":"1665331200.0"}
```

Firstly, it's clear the payloads are different.
You're using the `String(describing:)` initializer in Swift so `nonce` is being converted to a String rather than the raw floating-point value.

Secondly, `JSONSerialization.data` is escaping the forward slashes automatically when encoding. We can disable this optionally.

Now, other than the space between the keys in Python, the two outputs are the same.
Fixed example:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let date = formatter.date(from: "10/10/2022")

let payloadNonce = date!.timeIntervalSince1970
let payload: [String: Any] = [
    "request": "/v1/mytrades",
    "nonce": payloadNonce
]
            
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payload, options: .withoutEscapingSlashes)
    print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
    let b64 = json.base64EncodedString()
    print(b64)
} catch {
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Not too sure if you tried testing out your code, but I tried your code and the print of the decoded json isn't correct either. I got `{"request":"/v1/mytrades","nonce":1665331200}` instead, where the payloadNonce is missing the decimal places ".0". Any idea how do I fix this?

Comment: What you `see` printed, is just an artifact of the printing. You actually get a `Double` for the `nonce`. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593244/swift-jsonserialization-implicitly-convert-double-value-to-string

Answer (score 0):

When I decode the base64 strings, I get this for the Python code:

```
echo "eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjogIi92MS9teXRyYWRlcyIsICJub25jZSI6IDE2NjUzMzEyMDAuMH0=" | base64 -d
{"request": "/v1/mytrades", "nonce": 1665331200.0}
```

And this for the Swift code:

```
echo "eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjoiXC92MVwvbXl0cmFkZXMiLCJub25jZSI6IjE2NjUzMzEyMDAuMCJ9" | base64 -d
{"request":"\/v1\/mytrades","nonce":"1665331200.0"}
```

It appears that the slashes in the Swift code are escaped. To fix that, see this Stack Overflow answer: [Swift String escaping when serializing to JSON using Codable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076329/swift-string-escaping-when-serializing-to-json-using-codable).

The nonce is also a float in the Python response and a string in the Swift response.